# How to Return a View from a Controller to an iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I am new to MVC 3 and have come accross the following scenario:

**First let me explain how I have setup my application:**

All post backs to the server use jquery ajax which which return a view from the controller that either appended or prepended or replace a targeted div.

**The Scenario:**

I have come to a point where I would like to upload images but unfortunately because of the jquery ajax posting I cannot get the values for an html  in C# `Request.Files`. I know there are plugins out there to help out with this but I would like to do this myself so I have created an `<iframe>` which i then use a bit of javascript and post the form targeted to the iframe (old classic way of doing things):

```
function UploadImg(SACTION) {
        alert(SACTION);
        validatorform.action = SACTION;
        validatorform.target = "fraImage";
        validatorform.method = "POST";
        validatorform.submit();
    }
```

the `SACTION` parameter looks like this `@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Response")`. This all works well as it hits the controllers action method and I can then save the image:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(string ArticleID)
        {
            ViewBag.PreviewImage = cFileUploads.UploadFile(ArticleID, Request.Files[0]); 

            return View("ImagePreview");
        }
```

I would now like to return a view to the iframe (simply to preview the image and then do a couple of other things but this is besides the point)

The View for previewing the Image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<img alt="" src="@ViewBag.PreviewImage" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Problem:**

Unfortunately when I return the View (ImagePreview.cshtml) in C# the whole page is refreshed, all I want is for the iFrame to be refreshed. How should I return the view from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Fiqured out the problem, I had a bit of javascript that was replacing the contents of a div that the iframe was sitting in ... (slap on my forehead). All working perfectly now :)

Will leave this question here just incase ..